# GUI for patch command

Tags: gui, patch

Is there any GUI available for patch command? I need it because sometime I need to see the actual file before applying patch to it and it is very cumbersome to open patch file and then open the individual files listed in there. Even if I do that I cant compare the modified i.e patched file and unmodified/unpatched file.

Comment: Is the Stack Overflow question [A visual patch tool for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1879770/789593) helpful?

Comment: N.N. no. not really. Kompare seems like a nice tool. I am looking for something similar for Ubuntu.

Comment: [kompare is in Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/kompare)

Comment: N.N. Ya it is there in the repo but it is actually for Kubuntu. As the package description says "This package is part of the KDE Software Development Kit module" so installing it means installing all KDE dependencies and I am not willing to install all those.

Comment: There are lots of dependencies for it but there is also comments on Stack Overflow saying that its worth it. The thread [Patch GUI](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1611536) might be relevant even if it's a dead end.

Comment: Do you still have the problem. Have you found how to solved the problem or considered accepting an answer that solves your problem (if any)?

Answer (score 2):

When you open a patch file in emacs, you can put the cursor on a hunk and hit `C-c C-c` to jump to the corresponding location in the patched file and it will tell you if the patch has already been applied or not.  Then you can use `C-c C-a` to apply the hunk.